# Access database doesn't save decimal values correctly

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, decimal

I'm having some problems trying to save decimal values within a table in my Access database.

If I type the values, there is no problem, but when I try to save them using my program, the database won't save decimals and removes the `,`(8,7 turns into 87).

The field in the table is Decimal, Scale 2, Precision 8, and Decimal places 2.

I'm using this code to insert data:

```
Dim price as Decimal
ProductsTableAdapter.Insert(id,name,price)
```

I have tried to put the price as a `double` too and I still have the same problem.

I have looked on many places and read about changing the Datatype on the Access DB to `Double` but it didn't work.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

As [cybermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422013/cybermonkey) said the `Decimal` value is `8,7` so I tried to change it this way.

I changed the code to replace `,` for a `.`:

```
Dim price2 As String
price2 = price.ToString.Replace(",", ".")
ProductTableAdapter.Insert(id, name, price2)
```

Price 2 is `8.7`, but again the database shows `87,00`

**Edit 2:**

I have tried to create another project with a different db to determinate if the problem was this specific adapter or not, but i have the same problem again.

After that, i debug the program to see how the decimal value is stored and is: `8,7` instead of `8.7`. Then i try to insert data on the db and its the same if you put `8.7`or `8,7`, it works fine with those two values, so now i don't have any other idea of why this doesn't work.

Comment: The issue seems to be your localization, `Decimal` values have full stops (normally) but you're using a comma instead. What is your localization (system language)?

Comment: i have try to use both Decimal and Double on the DB and, VB program.

Comment: The issue is with the way .NET handles localization, see my answer for more information and for example code (example code is for SQL, but you should be able to convert to reading an Access database).

Comment: I've been looking into this issue and I find it perplexing. I'm going to look into it and then update my answer when I find the solution.

Comment: hardcoding it to change commas and dots is not how to convert a decimal value.  you need to answer the first question: what is your system culture setting and is the data in that same format or from a different culture?

Comment: @Plutonix It's to do with how .NET handles it rather than the localization. I tried this and got the same outcome as Fernando. (and yes my system is in English (Ireland)).

Comment: @Fernando I updated my answer with a solution that ***definitely*** works since I tested it myself. Please review it and if you found it solved your problem (which it should've), please upvote it (if you haven't already) and accept it.

Comment: If the database is forever and always formatting decimals with `,` then check that the system is using the correct culture.  I can only get Access to display decimals as ',' by changing the culture to one that format (ie France, Italy, not Ireland).

Comment: @Plutonix As explained before ***it has NOTHING to do with the culture and Microsoft Access.*** Moreover it's to do with how .NET was programmed in the first place, and I could reproduce this issue with a English-locale system. See my answer, it definitely works.

Comment: @Plutonix If it's because it's format from a different culture, How can i solve it?

Comment: @Fernando Please read what I'm telling you, it has absolutely nothing to do with your system's language but how .NET handles it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to recreate the issue. It appears to be an "unfortunate feature" of the Access OLEDB provider when operating on a machine where the Windows system locale does not use the period character (`.`) as the decimal symbol.

Using the following code

```vb
Dim price As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal("8,7")
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder("""price"" is a ")
sb.Append(price.GetType.FullName)
sb.Append(" whose value is ")
If price < 1 Or price > 10 Then
    sb.Append("NOT ")
End If
sb.Append("between 1 and 10.")
Debug.Print(sb.ToString)

ProductsTableAdapter.Insert("myProduct", price)
```

when I run it with Windows set to "English (United States)" I see the debug output

```
"price" is a System.Decimal whose value is NOT between 1 and 10.
```

and the value 87 is inserted into the database because the string "8,7" is not a valid decimal in that locale.

With Windows set to "Spanish (Spain)" the same code now produces

```
"price" is a System.Decimal whose value is between 1 and 10.
```

but the value 87 is still inserted.

With Windows set to "French (Canada)" the debug output is the same

```
"price" is a System.Decimal whose value is between 1 and 10.
```

however, the insert fails with "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

The exact same results were achieved by replacing

```vb
ProductsTableAdapter.Insert("myProduct", price)
```

with

```vb
Dim myConnStr As String
myConnStr =
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb"
Using con As New OleDbConnection(myConnStr)
    con.Open()
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Products ([name], price) VALUES (?,?)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "oledbTest")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", price)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

proving that this is a problem between `System.Data.OleDb` and the Access OLEDB provider, and not merely an idiosyncrasy of the TableAdapter. However, TableAdapters seem to rely exclusively on OleDb, so unfortunately they probably will just not work under these conditions.

The good news is that simply converting the OleDb code to Odbc appears to have fixed the issue for both the "Spanish (Spain)" and "French (Canada)" Windows locales

```vb
Dim myConnStr As String
myConnStr =
        "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" &
        "DBQ=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb"
Using con As New OdbcConnection(myConnStr)
    con.Open()
    Using cmd As New OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Products ([name], price) VALUES (?,?)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "odbcTest")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", price)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

so one possible workaround might be to use an OdbcDataAdapter instead of a TableAdapter.

Comment: Thanks for your Answers, i will test it as soon as i can.

Comment: I get an obdcException on `con.Open()` : `error im002 microsoft odbc driver manager data source name not found and no default driver specified`

Comment: Try `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}` (without the ", .accdb" bit) and see if that helps. If not, then open a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with details.

Comment: Completely ripped off my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that .NET is expecting you to provide the `Decimal` with a dot instead of a comma, which is due to how .NET handles localization (according to [this](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/437958-decimal-comma-point-problem-sql)).

This means that .NET is stripping out the `,` and instead of inserting your expected `8.7` you get `87`. This also explains why manually entering the data directly into the database works, but programmatically entering it does not.

Reading up on the issue it seems that using [`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) works, but however after some time I was able to do this by converting the `Decimal`into a `String Constant`:

```
Const price As String = "8,7"
Dim price2 As String
price2 = String.Format(price, _
price.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
ProductsTableAdapter.Insert(id,name,price)
```

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) states that you also need to `Import` the `Globalization` namespace using `Imports System.Globalization`.

Comment: I have tried that and again didn't work. I'm starting to think that the problem here is the Adapter, so i have destroy the DataSet and create a new one and still having the same problem.

Comment: @Fernando It worked for me, please tell me what language your system is using.

Comment: My system language is Spanish. If it helps, before i made this program, i work with VB.NET and Mysql and all works fine.

Then to test if the problem was the adapter or  not y create anoter project with another db with decimal values and was the same problem.

Comment: Testing with MsgBox() i discover that the decimal value is store as 8,7 instead 8.7 , and what's more, if you type a value directly on the db, takes the decimal number no matter if you put the decimal with a "," or a ".". So now im really lost.

Comment: @Fernando I'm at a loss too, because the code I wrote for you works, I tested it myself.

Comment: im gonna test more and i will put more edits if i get something usefull. thanks for your time anyway

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but working on a C# application,
just in case somebody has the same problem I'm gonna post what did the trick for me...

This is really bizzare but I found it on some forum with no explanation why it works.

When passing parameters of my SQL command all I did was add ToString() on the decimal parameter like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DecimalParameter", model.DecimalParameter.ToString());
```

And decimal value is now stored correctly!

Answer (score 0):

According to @Astopher, the problem is that, .NET is expecting you to provide the Decimal with a dot instead of a comma, which is due to how. Thus, I change the type of command parameter to varchar and it worked.

```
cm.Parameters.Add("@decimalcolum", OleDbType.VarChar);
cm.Parameters["@decimalcolum"].Value=decimalvalue;
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It was tested on Vietnamese, French(France), English(United states) region and language. I hope this problems solved!