# Data type mismatch in criteria expression when updating a typed dataset table's row

Tags: c#, ms-access, type-conversion, insert-update, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a typed dataset with one sample data table with an Integer ID field and a decimal Price field:

[image: Typed dataset with one sample data table]

The source database is an MS Access mdb file.
When I'm updating Price field I'm getting "*Data type mismatch in criteria expression*" error message in the case when MS Windows system wide decimal symbol is set to comma:

[image: Test fails when system wide decimal symbol is comma]

In the case when MS Windows system wide decimal symbol is set to dot, my test works well:

[image: Test runs well when system wide decimal symbol is set to comma]

Question: What would be **the minimal** correction of my sample code:

```
TestTableAdapter adapter = new TestTableAdapter();
ConsoleApplication2.SampleDataSet.TestDataTable table = adapter.GetData();
table[0].Price = 1.23m;
adapter.Update(table[0]);
```

to make it working well independent of the system wide decimal symbol setting value ?

Comment: I would stay away from typed datasets personally.. why don't you use SqlDataAdapter along with dataset / datatable to utilize the Fill() method and write code to do the update etc.. would be much less headache

Comment: @MethodMan: Thank you. My question is about a certain use case and its issues and its possible minimal efforts solution - my question is not about programming preferences. I mean I know how to solve the issue using untyped datasets but that wouldn't be a minimal efforts solution I'm looking for.

Comment: You seem to be encountering the deficiency in the Access OLEDB provider discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27944411/2144390). Your minimal-effort solution could very well be to do what @MethodMan suggests and stop using a TableAdapter, perhaps using an OdbcDataAdapter instead.

Comment: @Gord Thompson: Is that the Access OLEDB provider issue or [System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DbDataAdapter.cs) issue, which generates actual update commands on run-time ?

Comment: It is an issue with the Access OLEDB provider affecting fields (columns) that are defined as `Decimal` in an Access table. The issue does not seem to affect fields defined as `Currency`. It is also not a generic issue with DataAdapter objects because using an OleDbDataAdapter will fail but using an OdbcDataAdapter will work fine.

Comment: @Gord Thompson: Thank you, I have just posted a second now generic solution to the subject topic issue. When done it seems to be satisfying my original request for the *minimal efforts code correction* solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution:

```
var adapter = new TestTableAdapter();
adapter.Adapter.RowUpdating += new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatingEventHandler(
   (sender, e) =>
   {
     foreach (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter parameter in e.Command.Parameters)
          if (parameter.DbType == System.Data.DbType.Decimal)
              parameter.OleDbType = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Currency;
   }
);
ConsoleApplication2.SampleDataSet.TestDataTable table = adapter.GetData();
table[0].Price = 3.75m;
adapter.Update(table[0]);
```

This solution is a result of comments to this topic provided by [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) and some tests I have made here.

Answer (score 0):

The following "trick" of using "fake" parameters seems to be solving the subject issue. Every "fake" parameter has to be supplied with a custom "converter" code line - below is just a solution for the sample case not a generic solution. It can be generalized but I'd still expect to find more simple and generic solution:

```
var adapter = new TestTableAdapter();
adapter.Adapter.RowUpdating += 
   new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatingEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
      // UPDATE [Test] SET [Price] = {{Price}} WHERE [ID] = @id
      // {{Price}} is a fake parameter to be replaced by custom code
      e.Command.CommandText = e.Command.CommandText.Replace("{{Price}}", 
                 string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"),
                 "{0:#0.00}", 
                 e.Row["Price"])); 
     }
   );
ConsoleApplication2.SampleDataSet.TestDataTable table = adapter.GetData();
table[0].Price = 1.23m;
adapter.Update(table[0]);
```