# ADODB Datatype Decimal MS Access and SQL Server Decimal doesn't match?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010, adodb

i have some vb code which loads some data from an sql-server with this code snippet to a local table(both databases are connected via ADODB) :

adorec_local.Fields(str_array_fields(int_i, 1)) = adorec_server.Fields(str_array_fields(int_i, 2))

For example I have a decimal value on the server like "100.50". If this value is transfered to the local table the value in the table is shown as "10050" without the seperator.

When I look into the direct coding window the value is converted from "100.50" to "100,50" which seems correct to me. If I put this value directly into the local table it works without any issue.

Any ideas what's the problem here?

Both fields(local and server) are defined as decimal(8,2).

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Tried the "Double" datatype in Access and it works with the correct values. But I want the decimal value to stay consistent.

Comment: Is this an issue with regional settings, 100.50 and 100,50 could be interpreted differently, depending on where you are?

Comment: Are you using the OLEDB provider for your Access connection? If so, then you may be facing the issue addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27944411/2144390). TL;DR - Access OLEDB is somewhat broken for locales where the decimal separator is not `.`, but Access ODBC works in those circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I look for this tomorrow and I think this should be the solution :)