# Access database , Problems with comma "," and dot "." in decimals-values when inserting data in Access-db from c# windows form

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, sql-insert

[image]

I have problems with inserting decimal values into my Access database version (2007 - 2010).

Say I have following values in my textboxes: 
txtTotalAmount.Text = 3,5 
txtSalesTax.Text = 3,6 
txtTotalToPay.Text = 3,7

However, database values show: 
TotalAmount as 35 
SalesTax as 36 
TotalToPay as 37

My databse settings is as image shows .. 
And Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"].ConnectionString;
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [OrderItem](TotalAmount, SalesTax, TotalToPay) VALUES(@TotalAmount, @SalesTax, @TotalToPay)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalAmount", Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalAmount.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesTax", Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalesTax.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalToPay", Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalToPay.Text));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I tried even like this ;

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalToPay", decimal.Parse(txtToPay.Text));
```

and

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesTax", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTest.Text);
```

But geting the same problem. Please help.

Comment: Try examining the result of `Convert.ToDecimal(string)`.  It may be that your current culture does not have comma as a decimal separator.

Comment: also take a look at a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901356/access-database-doesnt-save-decimal-values-correctly also read up on what `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` means

Answer (score 0):

Very strange but I do not need to use Convert.ToDecimal ...  Just like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesTax", txtSalesTax.Text); Without converting and working fine in database ..;)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to  [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901356/access-database-doesnt-save-decimal-values-correctly), I think the problem is that, .NET is expecting you to provide the Decimal with a dot instead of a comma, which is due to how. Thus, I recommend that, using the type  OleDbType.VarChar instead of OleDbType.Decimal for that parameter
...

```
cm.Parameters.Add("@decimalcolum", OleDbType.VarChar);
cm.Parameters["@decimalcolum"].Value=decimalvalue;
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It was tested on Vietnamese, French(France), English(United states) region and language. I hope this problems solved!